# pandas duplicate rows and add column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df with hundreds of rows that looks like that:

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| IDx12 | 6 |
| IDx15 | 12 |

I want to replicate these rows 2 times, increment the `value` column for each duplication and add a column called `ratio` for each one of the newly created rows.
Here are the values of `ratio` I want for the created rows:

- original row = 0
- first duplication = 0.25
- second duplication = 0.5

So the output should look like this:

| ID | value | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IDx12 | 6 | 0 |
| IDx12 | 7 | 0.25 |
| IDx12 | 8 | 0.5 |
| IDx15 | 12 | 0 |
| IDx15 | 13 | 0.25 |
| IDx15 | 14 | 0.5 |

I found a very dumb way to do it by duplicating the df,incrementing `value` manually, adding a column with the `ratio` and then concatenating all the dfs.
But it's **very** unefficient. Do you have a smart way to do it?
thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe applying a lamda over the rows and inserting new ones with your criteria.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 2):

Below is a vectorised approach to the problem.

Create a dataframe with repeated rows

```
rdf = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, 3, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
```

Create a column to hold number of repeats

```
rdf['repeat'] = 1
rdf['repeat'] = rdf.groupby('ID').repeat.cumsum() - 1
```

Add the repeat to value

```
rdf['value'] += rdf['repeat']
```

Create the ratio column

```
rdf['ratio'] = rdf.repeat * 0.25
```

Voila! The output is

```
      ID value  repeat  ratio
0  IDx12     6       0   0.00
1  IDx12     7       1   0.25
2  IDx12     8       2   0.50
3  IDx15    12       0   0.00
4  IDx15    13       1   0.25
5  IDx15    14       2   0.50
```